# BIOS splash screen and Linux Mint disk unencryption disappeared

Tags: linux, bios, linux-mint, disk-encryption, splash

I'm on Linux Mint 18.2 with my AMD Ryzen 7 1700 and an NVidia GTX 1060 GPU.

Linux 4.10.0-42-generic #46~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 4 15:57:59 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 18.2 Sonya
Release:    18.2
Codename:   sonya

The SSD where I mounted `/` is encrypted with password.
For some reason at every reboot of my system I don't see the BIOS splash screen and the screen remains black.
I need to manually `Ctrl + Alt + Canc` in order to let the unencryption dialog appear, and after that Linux Mint starts.

Do someone know why I cannot see nor the BIOS informations (memory system etc) nor the unencryption dialog?

Comment: Probably related with the Nvidia drivers. Several similar issues have been reported in the past.

Comment: Looks like if the unencryption dialog shows up in full resolution mode, it gets black. I need to reboot via keyboard in order to restart it in low-resolution mode (like when you do `Ctrl + Alt + F1` to enter a tty session)